# Transitioning Controllers Animation - Variable binding in a condition requires an initializer

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to follow a simple tutorial on making a circular transition from one viewController to the secondViewController.

However Xcode gives me an error that isn't encountered in tutorial and not sure how to deal with it.

[Variable binding in a condition requires an initializer error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXk1D.png)

```
import UIKit

class CircularTransition: NSObject {

    var circle = UIView()

    var startingPoint = CGPoint.zero {
        didSet {
            circle.center = startingPoint
        }
    }

    var circleColor = UIColor.white

    var duration = 0.3

    enum CircularTransitionMode: Int {
        case present, dismiss, pop
    }

    var transition:CircularTransitionMode = .present
}

extension CircularTransition:UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {
    func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
        return duration
    }

    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        let containerView = transitionContext.containerView

        var CircularTransitionMode: CircularTransitionMode
        if CircularTransitionMode == .present {
            if case let presentedView == transitionContext.view(forKey: UITransitionContextViewKey.to) {

                let viewCenter = presentedView.center
                let viewSize = presentedView.frame.size

                circle = UIView()

            }
        }
        else{

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues with the animateTransition function.

First the line with the error should be this:

```
if let presentedView = transitionContext.view(forKey: UITransitionContextViewKey.to) {
```

because you don't need the case check and you are trying to assign not compare so it's = not ==.

Second you create a variable of type CircularTansitionMode but don't assign anything to it in this line:

```
var CircularTransitionMode: CircularTransitionMode
```

and then immediately try to use it.

Fixing your original error will then flag this second one up on the next line saying it is being used without being initialised.

You also have a lot of unused variables but maybe you just haven't posed the complete code.